# String parsing with batch scripting

Tags: windows, string, parsing, batch-file, xml-parsing

I have a file called **pictures.xml** and it contains some pictures information like:

```
<ResourcePicture Name="a.jpg">
        <GeneratedPicture Name="b.jpg"/>            
        <GeneratedPicture Name="c.jpg"/>
</ResourcePicture>

<ResourcePicture Name="z1.jpg">
        <GeneratedPicture Name="z2.jpg"/>
        <GeneratedPicture Name="z3.jpg"/>
        <GeneratedPicture Name="z4.jpg"/>
</ResourcePicture>
```

What I want do do is to get **each line** in for loop and print the **names of the pictures**. Sample output like:

1. a.jpg - b.jpg c.jpg
2. z1.jpg - z2.jpg z3.jpg z4.jpg

I can get each line but can't get the **name** attributes

```
    for /f "Delims=/" %%a in (pictures.xml) do ( 
        echo %%a
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in (pictures.xml) DO (
    SET b=%%a
    SET b=!b:"=+!
    FOR /F "delims=+ tokens=2" %%c in ("!b!") DO (
        ECHO %%c
    )
)
```

This will output only `something.jpg`. Here the expülanation:
First we split the file into lines. Now we want to find the something.jpg in each line and output only these tokens. So we can split the lines with `"` as delimeter and take the second substring. But we can't use `"` as delim because CMD won't accept this. That's why we first replace `"` with `+`. If `+` can appear in your code use a different character that is accepted as delimeter but won't be in your xml file.

Finally we can now split eacht line using `+` as delimeter and take the 2nd substring of each line which will result in only the file names.

EDIT: Here's how to check if your line starts with "ResourcePicture":

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (pictures.xml) do (
    SET b=%%a
    SET prefix=!b:~1,15!
    IF !prefix!==ResourcePicture (
        SET b=!b:"=+!
        FOR /F "delims=+ tokens=2" %%c in ("!b!") DO (
            ECHO %%c
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can figure out if the current line contains ResourcePicture with a simple if statement as well?

Comment: "contains" is not that simple but you can check if it starts with "<ResourcePicture". I'll add the code to my answer.

Comment: Done. The key is `SET prefix=!b:~1,15!`. This skips the first char of the string and takes 15 chars starting with the second index so "<ResourcePicture Name="a.jpg">" becomes "ResourcePicture".

Comment: You are a pro! Thank you so much again.